# SO-Jobs prompting for 'Where did you hear about us' is missing SOJobs

Tags: discussion

I was applying to some job, which had a mark saying, `Easy Apply`. So the entire form filling happened on SOJobs page.

In the form it asked 'Where did you hear about us'? And unfortunately, SOJobs is missing from the list.
[image: As Seen here]